# Reading from a streaming syslog server using R

Tags: r, stream, syslog, rsyslog

I am getting CISCO ASA VPN logs in my local live syslog server. Since the data is largely unstructured, I want to process each log and then store the data in a table(preferably hive).

Any code I wrote till now is very basic readLines and connection commands such as opening the syslog and writing the last few lines in an output using-

```
zz <- file("/home/akashb/write.data","w")
logread <- file("/var/log/messages","r")
x <- readLines(logread,-1)
cat(x[(length(x)-1):length(x)],file=zz,sep="\n")
```

I want to make it in such a way that R takes each new log generated and  process those logs and store the output in some place. That is the connection must be in running always in the background.

Also since the volume of the log will be very high in little time, what kind of pressure I should expect on my RAM, or can it be done in such a way where only one line is processed at a time.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: There are a plethora of non-R, free, already-baked solutions for this very task — including streaming into Hive. Is there a reason this has to be in R?

Comment: I am restructuring the data getting only relevant fields using REGEX. Only reason for using R is I'm comfortable with using R. can you name the other softwares?

Comment: I would take a look at Apache NiFi — https://nifi.apache.org/docs.html. There is a docker container for it as well — https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/nifi/ — so you can run it w/o adding cruft to your system. With a little bit of effort this can likely do what you need and has been built for tasks like this. It's unlikely a custom-baked R solution will come close the the long-term stability and performance of tailor made streaming log systems.

Comment: does NiFi work if I only need specific type of logs say with a keyword and each type of logs are differently formatted?